# Show that $[x] + [x + \frac{1}2] = [2x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am getting the solution, but only for one case.

Ignoring the case where $x$ may be an integer.

For $[x]$, there exists a real number non integer $\delta$ such that $0 \lt \delta \lt 1$.

Therefore,

$x - \delta = [x]$

Now for $[x + \frac{1}2]$ -

if $\delta \ge \frac{1}2$, $[x + \frac{1}2] = [x] + 1$, on the other hand if $\delta \lt \frac{1}2$, $[x + \frac{1}2] = [x]$

So for the first case, the answer becomes $[2x] + 1$, while for the second case, I get what is expected $[2x]$.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error is to use $[x]+[x]= [2x]$, which is not always true. Take for example $x=1,7$.

Comment: Every time that $x-[x] \geq \frac{1}{2}$ (assuming $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$), indeed ;)

Comment: "So for the first case, the answer becomes [2x]+1"  No.  It becomes $2[x]+1$.  ", while for the second case, I get what is expected [2x]" No.  It becomes $2[x]$.   $2[x]+1$ is not the same thing as $[2x]+1$ and $2[x]$ is not the same thing as $[2x]$.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct, but you missed some details. You can write $x = n + \delta$ as you noted, where $\delta \in [0,1)$.

If $\delta < 1/2$ then $x+1/2 = n + \delta'$ with $\delta' = \delta + 1/2 < 1$ and $2x = 2n +\delta'$ with $\delta'' = 2\delta <1$, and then $[x] + [x+1/2] = n + n = 2n = [2x]$.

If $\delta > 1/2$, then $x+1/2 = n+1 + \delta'$ where $\delta' = \delta - 1/2$ and $2x = 2n + 1 + \delta''$ where $\delta'' =  2\delta -1  < 1$ so that $[x] + [x+1/2] = n + n+1 = 2n+1 = [2x]$.

Comment: (I assumed that $[x]$ means the nearest integer smaller than $x$ given that you assumed that $\delta > 0$, but similar ideas work for other integer functions.)

Answer (score 0):

For all real we have $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

it follows $\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac12\rfloor-\lfloor 2x\rfloor=0$ is equivalent to $$\dfrac12+\{2x\}=\{x\}+\{x+\dfrac12\}\hspace 1cm (*)$$
we have in $(*)$ when $x$ is integer and when $x=\dfrac12$, respectively
$$\dfrac12+0=0+\dfrac12\\\dfrac12+0=\dfrac12+0$$ so we have to look at the two cases
$0\lt x\lt\dfrac12$ and $\dfrac12\lt x\lt1$. In the first case we have in $(*)$
$$\dfrac12+2x=x+x+\dfrac12$$  When finally $\dfrac12\lt x\lt1$, put $x=\dfrac12+\delta$ where $0\lt\delta\lt\dfrac12$ so $(*)$ becomes

$$\dfrac12+\{1+2\delta\}=\{\dfrac12+\delta\}+\{1+\delta\}$$ which is equal to
$$\dfrac12+1+2\delta=\dfrac12+\delta+1+\delta$$
We are done.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistakenly assuming that $[2x] = 2[x]$.

That is only true if $x= [x] + \delta$ and $\delta < \frac 12$.

(In that case.   $2x = 2[x] + 2\delta < 1$ so $[2x] = 2[x]$.

If if $x = [x] + \delta$ and $\delta \ge \frac 12$ you get $2x = 2[x] + 2\delta \ge 2[x] + 1$ so $[2x] =2[x]+1$.

.....

Hence in case 1: $\delta \ge \frac 12$ you get $[x]+[x+\frac 12] = 2[x] +1 = [2x]$.  Which is FINE!

And in case 2: $\delta < \frac 12$ yot get $[x] + [x+\frac 12] = 2[x] = [2x]$.

But that is *only* fine because $\delta < \frac 12$.

=======

In general,  $[nx] \ne n[x]$.

Instead if there is a fraction, $\frac jn; j,n \in \mathbb N; j<n$, so that $[x] + \frac jn \le x < [x] + \frac {j+1}n$ then  $[nx] = n[x] +j$.  (The proof is left to you as an excercise.)